# MongoDB schema design to support editing subdocuments within an array in multi-user environment?

Tags: mongodb, schema

Let's suppose I have a basic blog web app using the following document schema for a blog post.

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    title: "Blog Post #1",
    text: "<p>This is my blog post!</p>",
    comments: [
        {
            user: "username1",
            time: Date(...),
            text: "This is a great blog post!"
        },
        {
            user: "username2",
            time: Date(...),
            text: "This is even better than sliced bread!"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's all well and good, but now let's suppose that a user can edit or delete his comment.  On top of that, it's a web app, so there could be multiple people editing or deleting their comments at the same time.  Now suppose I am logged in as "username2" and try to edit my comment, which is the 2nd item in the comments array - index position 1.  Just before I click "save", user1 logs in and deletes his comment which is the 1st item in the array.  If my code tries to delete user 2's comment by index position, it will fail because there are no longer 2 items in the array.

Two ideas came to mind, but I'm not crazy about either one.

- create some sort of id on each comment
- create a "lastModified" timestamp on the parent document, and only save the edit if nothing has changed on the document.

What is the best way to handle this type of situation?  If I really need an id on each comment, will I have to generate it myself?  What data type should it be?  Or would it be best to use both of my ideas together?  Or is there another option I'm not even thinking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having different writers is a key downside of embedding documents in my opinion. You might want to take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077202/in-mongodb-is-it-practical-to-keep-all-comments-for-a-post-in-one-document/11079459) that presents different solutions. I'd try to avoid different writers to one document and use a separate `Comments` collection instead, where each comment is owned by its author. You can fetch all comments on a post by an indexed field `postId` reasonably fast. Then the comments simply have a regular `_id` field. It makes sense to use an `ObjectId` because that automatically stores the time the comment was created, and it's a monotonic index by default.

> create a "lastModified" timestamp on the parent document, and only save the edit if nothing has changed on the document.

This is called 'optimistic locking' and it's generally not good if there is a high probability of concurrent operations. In the case of blog posts, it's likely that newer posts receive a lot more comments than older ones, so I'd say the collision proability is kinda high.

There's yet another nasty side-effect: let's say the blog post author wants to modify the text but someone adds or removes a comment in the mean time. Now even the blog author wouldn't be able to change the text unless you use the atomic `$set` operation on the text and bypass the version check.